# Select all in checkbox at the same time with multiple select all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can I ask how to code a "select all" in a checkbox at the same time with multiple select all?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.allcheckboxes').click(function() {
      $(this).next().parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('checkallbox');

      if($('#selectall_wrapper').hasClass('checkallbox')) {

          $('#selectall_wrapper input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);

      } else {
          $('#selectall_wrapper input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="selectall_wrapper">
    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkedall" class="allcheckboxes" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkedall">Select all services</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox1">Service 1</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox2">Service 2</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox3">Service 3</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>


<ul id="selectall_wrapper">
    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkedall" class="allcheckboxes" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkedall">Select all products</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox1">product 1</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox2">product 2</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox3">product 3</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please don't use these kind of tricks to get around the 'fiddle without code' warning. Put all your code in the question so that 1) if jsFiddle goes down your question is still answerable 2) you get quicker and more clear ansers

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, you can use another wrapper and add that to your function. (this could be cleaned up and greatly simplified, but you get the idea.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.allcheckboxes').click(function() {
      $(this).next().parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('checkallbox');

      if($('#selectall_wrapper').hasClass('checkallbox')) {

          $('#selectall_wrapper input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);

      } else{
          $('#selectall_wrapper input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
      }  if($('#selectall_wrapper_2').hasClass('checkallbox')) {

          $('#selectall_wrapper_2 input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);

      } else {
          $('#selectall_wrapper_2 input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="selectall_wrapper">
    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkedall" class="allcheckboxes" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkedall">Select all services</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox1">Service 1</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox2">Service 2</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox3">Service 3</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>


<ul id="selectall_wrapper_2">
    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkedall_2" class="allcheckboxes" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkedall_2">Select all products</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox1">product 1</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox2">product 2</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox3">product 3</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```